# Delete Text between two strings sed, awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed, substitution

I was searching for a solution, but could not find a proper one.

I want to remove all characters between two strings on every line.

Input is a Fasta-File:

```
>CAM_P0000101_READ_00457523 /accession=CAM_P0000101_READ_00457523 /xy=2625_3790 /region=2 /run=R_2008_08_11_16_51_31_ /length=253 /sample_id=1309720343513924875 /sample_acc=CAM_P0000101_SMPL_PAPUT2 /sample_name=CAM_P0000101_SMPL_PAPUT2 /site_id_n=CAM_P0000101_SITE_PAPUT2
GTGCCTTCGGGAACCGGGTGACAGGTGCTGCATGGCTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGTAACGAGCGCAACCCTTGTCCTTAGTTGCCAGCACGTAATGGTGGGAACTCTAAGGAGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGACGACGTCAAGTCATCATGGCCCTTACGGCCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGCTAGGACAGACGGCTGCAAACCNGCGAGTGGGG
>CAM_P0000101_READ_00460168 /accession=CAM_P0000101_READ_00460168 /xy=2199_0493 /region=2 /run=R_2008_08_11_16_51_31_ /length=233 /sample_id=1309720343513924875 /sample_acc=CAM_P0000101_SMPL_PAPUT2 /sample_name=CAM_P0000101_SMPL_PAPUT2 /site_id_n=CAM_P0000101_SITE_PAPUT2
TTTACCGCGGCTGCTGGCACGAAGTTAGCCGGACCTTATTCTTCGGGTACAGTCATTATCTTTCCCGACAAAAGAGCTTTACAACCCAAGGGCCTTCTTCACTCACGCGGCATCGCTGCATCAGGCTTTCGCCCATTGTGCAAGATTCCCCACTGCTGCCTCCCGTAGGAGTCTGGGCCGTATCTCAGTCCCAGTGTGGCTGATCATCCTCTACAAATCAGCTATTGATTACT
```

I want to delete all text after first `>CAM_P*` to `/sample_name=*` and all after `sample_name.*`

`>CAM_* /sample_name=*` only these two things should remain.

all this should be removed :

```
/accession=CAM_P0000101_READ_00457523 /xy=2625_3790 /region=2 /run=R_2008_08_11_16_51_31_ /length=253 /sample_id=1309720343513924875 /sample_acc=CAM_P0000101_SMPL_PAPUT /site_id_n=CAM_P0000101_SITE_PAPUT2
```

Could anyone please help me ?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Why don't you just `print ">CAM_* /sample_name=*"` instead of bothering with any substitutions? You have 2 lines of input but only 1 line of output - why?

Comment: What about the `GTGCCTTCGGGAACCG...`? Do you want that removed or left intact?

Answer (score 2):

awk to the rescue

```
awk '{line=""; sep=""; p=q=0; 
      for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
          if(!p && $i~/CAM_P/) {
              p=1;
              line=line sep $i;
              sep=FS
          } else if(!q && $i~/sample_name/) {
              q=1;
              line=line sep $i;
              sep=FS
          }
       } 
       print line
      }'
```

another alternative with `grep`

```
grep -o ">CAM_P\w*\|/sample_name=\w*" filename | awk 'ORS=NR%2?FS:RS'
```

match the two words only and merge back two lines of the output

Comment: Thanks, but I get an Error Message:   <br/>                                            awk -f short_name_fasta.awk test  <br/> 
awk: short_name_fasta.awk:3: awk '{line=""; sep="";   <br/>
awk: short_name_fasta.awk:3:     ^ invalid char ''' in expression  <br/>
awk: short_name_fasta.awk:3: awk '{line=""; sep="";   <br/>
awk: short_name_fasta.awk:3:     ^ syntax error

Comment: The script shouldn't have the `awk` in it, nor the single quotes.  Please confirm. Only include what's between the single qutoes.    Or, your copy/paste might have grabbed some invalid chars from the webpage.

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer if it's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
sed 's/\(>CAM_P[^ ]*\).*\(\/sample_name=[^ ]*\).*/\1 \2/' filename
```